# Cakephp: use OR conditions in userScope

Tags: cakephp, authentication

I'm trying to create a login function in Cake 1.3.10 that checks an extra condition apart from username and password. I'm using the $this->Auth->userScope for that.

If I check just one condition it works fine. I have this in my beforeFilter():

```
 $this->Auth->userScope = array('User.status' => 1);
```

However, if I use and **OR** (like in the finds) it doesn't work:

```
$this->Auth->userScope = array('OR'=> array('User.status' => 1, 'User.status' => 2));
```

Doing that it ignores the first condition of the **OR**, just considering the second one.

Is there any way to acheive this with userScope?

Comment: what cake version? you should always mention the exact version you are using. because in 2.x this would not work this way ( http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/authentication.html#configuring-authentication-handlers ).

Comment: @mark you're right, I forgot, it's Cake 1.3.10 (just edited the question to include that)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basic PHP.
It does not ignore it, but due to the nature of arrays overwrites the first with the second.
You may never use the same key in an array more than once.

So it's:

```
$this->Auth->userScope = array(
    'OR' => array(array('User.status' => 1), array('User.status' => 2)))
```

Or in your case, since its CakePHP we are talking about, the cleaner solution (to merge them):

```
$this->Auth->userScope = array('User.status' => array(1, 2));
```

Which will be transformed in a simple "IN (1, 2)" statement.

Comment: thanks for your reply. The thing about "basic PHP" is a little relative, it depends on how each function treats the input arrays. For example in a find() it works just like I had it without merging the 2 elements for having the same key...

Comment: No it doesn't. It can't. Trust me.

Comment: I have "finds" using OR conditions like that one in other places, and they work perfectly fine, trust me ;)

Comment: @Albert you cannot change [how php works](https://gist.github.com/AD7six/5916195), you cannot be referring to the same thing you've asked about in the question (if you want clarification show what you are talking about).

Comment: Well, clearly we're not understanding each other, my comments with @mark are to point out that I use conditions like that in a **find()** method and they work, I'm not changing how PHP works. Anyways, I got the response to my original question, so we're good :)

Comment: And we both told you now more than once that this is absolutely impossible. Show us some codezzz (bin.cakephp.org for example and link it) and we believe you.